# How to find out which tab is active in React Navigation TopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is my code:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Page1"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#000000',
                labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
                style: { backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', height: 45},
            }}

        >

            
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Page2"
                component={Page2}


                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Page2' }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Page3"
                component={Page3}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Page3' }}
            />

        </Tab.Navigator>
```

So here is my question, I need to know which tab is active at a given time to recieve some data from the database. Ideally a state contains the id or name of the active tab.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom hook which uses [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook from React Navigation. Then you can provide this custom hook to your screens.

```
const useCustomHookOnFocus = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(user));

        return () => unsubscribe();
      }, [])
  );
};

const YourScreen = () => {
   useCustomHookOnFocus();
}
```

Also you can get [navigation state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/) and check whether you are in the screen or not like this:

```
const state = useNavigationState(state => state);
state.routes.map((route, index) => {
  const isFocused = state.index === index;
}
```